# click event listeners attached to document.body dont fire in iOS6?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, ios6, delegation

Experiencing strange behaviour and non functioning event delegation in iOS6, the root of which is that if I simply attach an event handler to document.body, as so:

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(){alert("ios6 sucks")}, false);
```

this doesnt get run, for example if I go to google.com and add that via safari remote webinspector. In some cases it will run, including if I click on a link on the page, or if clicking on an element that has an event handler attached directly to it. The same works fine in major browsers and on iOS 5 and 4. Adding touchend to body will trigger as it should and could be a potential workaround but it is really preferable to let the browser detect clicks instead of having to program some click detection in touchstart/touchend. Am wondering if this is an iOS6 bug. but I havent seen anyone else complain about this yet.

Comment: following my findings, if I attach a click handler to a div that sits alone as a direct child of body, wrapping the whole page, then that will work. And as a side effect, that will make the body click event trigger as well... if there is no event attached to the child div, then as before no event triggers on body.

Answer (score 0):

@Bonkers ... Referencing why the body click gets triggered after attaching the click event to the div is solely due to event bubbling.

I replicated your code here showing that it gets called twice on the div but only once on the body:

```
<div id="myDiv">FlackAttack Test</div>

<script>
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(){alert("ios6 sucks")}, false);
document.getElementById('myDiv').addEventListener('click', function(){alert("ios6 sucks twice")},      false);
</script>
```

If you wanted to stop the event from bubbling, you could call e.stopPropagation(); or e.cancelBubble = true;

Comment: Yes, which is fine but thats not the bug, the bug is that the listener attached to the body doesnt react. Whereas in iOS5 it does.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem. The following helped (omitting .body):

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(){alert("ios6 sucks")}, false);
```